Identifying unmarked IC in CNC controller board
I have a Camxtool v3.5 CNC controller (similar to this, although this is v3.4) that has an unmarked IC that I haven't been able to identify:

The IC is connected between pin PB3 of the ATmega328P (used as a PWM output) and a photocoupler (EL357N). The output of the photocoupler then connects to a N-channel MOSFET used to control the speed of the CNC spindle.
I also found an schematic (which I guess is not official) that shows how everything is connected, but does not identify the IC:

The schematic shows a NOT gate to negate the PWM signal before the photocoupler. Does anyone know this specific IC?

looks like there is a sticker on top of the IC

I double checked and it is not a sticker.

The markings may have been intentionally removed to hinder reverse engineering.

There's various dirt all over the PCB so in case you are trying to repair it, start with isopropyl and clean it. And if it's metallic dust/dust with metal particles, then anything can happen.

On my board the marking is not completely deleted. With some effort I read STC 15F104W, it appears to be a little microcontroller.
Here is a link to a datasheet for the STC15F101 serie which include the STC15F104 too.
It is a microcontroller based on 1T architecture 80C51 CPU.
This is a copy of the pinning from the datasheet, which matches the used pins:


Welcome to SE/EE! Please take the [tour] to learn more about this site, and you might want to read some of the [help]. -- Your answer seems to identify the IC correctly. Would you mind to [edit] it to extend it with a bit more information, like a link to a data sheet and pinning details?
